# Match and extract element between two arrays of objects by _id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

**Array One:**

```
[
  {
    "value": {
      "_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1",
      "is_default": false,
      "is_required": true,
      "sort_order": 0,
      "value": "",
      "label": "No 38",
      "option_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d0",
      "__v": 0,
      "selected": true
    }
  },
  {
    "value": {
      "label": "Τρικολορ",
      "sort_order": 0,
      "value": "#7a3131|#0e8e76|#b6edd9",
      "_id": "3aa5b2d7-cb78-44ce-bb5d-e4d42ebf3309",
      "selected": true
    }
  },
  {
    "value": {
      "label": "ΧΛ",
      "sort_order": 0,
      "value": "",
      "_id": "5df37c50854df50b274d7829",
      "selected": true
    }
  }
]
```

**Array Two:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5df384edba99411550e4e019",
    "options": [
      {
        "option": {
          "sort_order": 0,
          "display_name": "Μέγεθος (EU)",
          "type": "text",
          "display_style": "dropdown"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1",
          "is_default": false,
          "is_required": true,
          "sort_order": 0,
          "value": "",
          "label": "No 38",
          "option_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d0",
          "__v": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "display_name": "swatch",
          "display_style": "swatch",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "type": "swatch"
        },
        "value": {
          "label": "Τρικολορ",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "value": "#7a3131|#0e8e76|#b6edd9",
          "_id": "3aa5b2d7-cb78-44ce-bb5d-e4d42ebf3309"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "display_name": "dropdown",
          "display_style": "dropdown",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "type": "multiplechoice"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5df37c61854df50b274d782a",
          "is_default": false,
          "is_required": true,
          "label": "Λ",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "value": "",
          "value_data": null
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1",
    "options": [
      {
        "option": {
          "sort_order": 0,
          "display_name": "Μέγεθος (EU)",
          "type": "text",
          "display_style": "dropdown"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1",
          "is_default": false,
          "is_required": true,
          "sort_order": 0,
          "value": "",
          "label": "No 38",
          "option_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d0",
          "__v": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "display_name": "swatch",
          "display_style": "swatch",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "type": "swatch"
        },
        "value": {
          "label": "Τρικολορ",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "value": "#7a3131|#0e8e76|#b6edd9",
          "_id": "3aa5b2d7-cb78-44ce-bb5d-e4d42ebf3309"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "display_name": "dropdown",
          "display_style": "dropdown",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "type": "multiplechoice"
        },
        "value": {
          "label": "ΧΛ",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "value": "",
          "_id": "5df37c50854df50b274d7829"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, each `value` `_id` from element at index 1 in `Array Two` matches each `value` `_id` from `Array One`.

How can I iterate `Array Two` and extract the `_id` if all elements `value` `_id`'s matches `Array One`?

I have tried so many approaches but none seems to work, e.x.:

```
    const opts = newTempProduct.variants.map((item) => item.options);
    const props = ['_id'];
    const result = opts
      .filter((o1, i) => {
        o1.filter((o3) => {
          return tmpVariant.some((o2) => {
            return o3.value._id === o2.value._id;
          });
        });
      })
      .map(function(o) {
        return props.reduce((newo, name) => {
          newo[name] = o[name];
          return newo;
        }, {});
      });
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your expected result?

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the comment, I just want the _id from the second array, in this case `5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1`. It's ok though if I could get the whole object with that `_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an additional array called `search`. This array is a mapped version of your first array, to only include the `_id` property. For efficiency purposes, you can make this array a `Set` so you can have O(1) lookup. You can then use `.every()` with `.filter()` to return `true` if all ids in the `options` array for a given object are in `search` array. This will give you your resulting id:

```js
const arr = [{ "value": { "_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1", "is_default": false, "is_required": true, "sort_order": 0, "value": "", "label": "No 38", "option_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d0", "__v": 0, "selected": true } }, { "value": { "label": "Τρικολορ", "sort_order": 0, "value": "#7a3131|#0e8e76|#b6edd9", "_id": "3aa5b2d7-cb78-44ce-bb5d-e4d42ebf3309", "selected": true } }, { "value": { "label": "ΧΛ", "sort_order": 0, "value": "", "_id": "5df37c50854df50b274d7829", "selected": true } } ]; 
const data = [{ "_id": "5df384edba99411550e4e019", "options": [{ "option": { "sort_order": 0, "display_name": "Μέγεθος (EU)", "type": "text", "display_style": "dropdown" }, "value": { "_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1", "is_default": false, "is_required": true, "sort_order": 0, "value": "", "label": "No 38", "option_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d0", "__v": 0 } }, { "option": { "display_name": "swatch", "display_style": "swatch", "sort_order": 0, "type": "swatch" }, "value": { "label": "Τρικολορ", "sort_order": 0, "value": "#7a3131|#0e8e76|#b6edd9", "_id": "3aa5b2d7-cb78-44ce-bb5d-e4d42ebf3309" } }, { "option": { "display_name": "dropdown", "display_style": "dropdown", "sort_order": 0, "type": "multiplechoice" }, "value": { "_id": "5df37c61854df50b274d782a", "is_default": false, "is_required": true, "label": "Λ", "sort_order": 0, "value": "", "value_data": null } } ] }, { "_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1", "options": [{ "option": { "sort_order": 0, "display_name": "Μέγεθος (EU)", "type": "text", "display_style": "dropdown" }, "value": { "_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d1", "is_default": false, "is_required": true, "sort_order": 0, "value": "", "label": "No 38", "option_id": "5ce3f8cc35ad1e0999ee18d0", "__v": 0 } }, { "option": { "display_name": "swatch", "display_style": "swatch", "sort_order": 0, "type": "swatch" }, "value": { "label": "Τρικολορ", "sort_order": 0, "value": "#7a3131|#0e8e76|#b6edd9", "_id": "3aa5b2d7-cb78-44ce-bb5d-e4d42ebf3309" } }, { "option": { "display_name": "dropdown", "display_style": "dropdown", "sort_order": 0, "type": "multiplechoice" }, "value": { "label": "ΧΛ", "sort_order": 0, "value": "", "_id": "5df37c50854df50b274d7829" } } ] } ];

const search = new Set(arr.map(({value: {_id}}) => _id));
const res = data.filter(
  ({options}) => options.every(({value: {_id}}) => search.has(_id))
).map(({_id}) => _id); // use `.filter()` incase many objects match ur first array

console.log(res); // array of all _ids matched
console.log(res.pop()); // your expected/wanted result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can't get rid of `selected:true` it's there for other reasons needed elsewhere in the app. The source of truth is only the `_id` of each `value`. I almost tried your approach by deleting the `selected` property but then I was noted that it's required...I will try this one and come back.

Comment: @StathisNtonas Hi, I've modified my answer a bit to only look at the `_id` property